# Trigger MYSQL ERROR 1442

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE   TRIGGER `Salary` AFTER UPDATE ON `employee` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 IF OLD.time_out <> NEW.time_out THEN
 UPDATE employee SET time_work=TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in);
 END IF;

    END;


DELIMITER ;
```

AND I USE THIS QUERY

UPDATE `DataBase`.`employee` SET `time_out`='2014-10-22 16:41:09' WHERE `IDREC`='4945'

THERE Error Code : 1442
Can't update table 'employee' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: yes you can not do insert/delete/update operation on the same table where you are executing the trigger . At best you can set the value as `set new.time_work=TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in);`

Comment: FWIW, you can't change `NEW.time_work` in an AFTER trigger.

Comment: ah @BillKarwin you are correct its an after update trigger so set would not work here, it needs to be before update .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a table (employee) where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate **Error 1442**:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'employee' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

---

**Solution**: instead of `AFTER UPDATE ON`, make it a `BEFORE UPDATE ON` trigger, to set the new value for the field, before inserting - if `time_work` is a field in the new entry, you need to update just before insert - the probable SQL 'd be (not tested):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Salary` BEFORE UPDATE ON `employee` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF OLD.time_out <> NEW.time_out THEN
            SET NEW.time_work=TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in);
        END IF;
    END;
DELIMITER ;
```